# Is there a way to retry a Bolt in Storm?

Tags: java, apache-storm

We have an app that does database saves.  If the save fails, is there a way to retry just the bolt that failed?  We don't want to fail all the way back to the spout.

Answer (score 2):

You could add an output "scorpion tail" stream to the bolt.  The stream would be read by whichever bolt would begin the retry process.  This would create a loop in the topology. The idea is that when a failure occurs, you can write a packet of information to this stream and have the tuple delivered to the upstream bolt that would begin the retry.  The packet contains whatever state is needed for the retry.

Comment: this answer. + if you notice the tuples are coming from the "scorpion tail" stream, the retry policy should be different (eg. a longer timeout).

Answer (score 1):

There is no build-in support for this in Storm. However, you can code you own solution:

1. Do not ack (or fail) the failing tuple, buffer it in an internal data structure (ie, member variable; maybe a `List`), and return from `execute()`
2. Keep processing further tuples in `execute()` until you want to retry (maybe some timer, ie, you might want to get current timestamp or you retry counter based).
3. On retry, before processing the new input tuple, receive the failed tuple from your buffer and try to insert into DB. If it fails again, insert into buffer again. If insert is successful, ack buffered tuple and resume processing current input tuple.

You only need to consider Storm's `MESSAGE_TIMEOUT`. Retrying cannot take longer than this value because if the tuple gets not acked within the timeout value, Storm fails the tuple at the source automatically.